# Make Two Google charts in the same page

Tags: javascript, charts

I am triying to put two google charts of the same style, but when i try it, one is visible and one didnt appear.

So, here's the code.

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales'],
      ['2014', 1000],
      ['2015', 1170],
      ['2016', 660],
      ['2017', 1030]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

What variables I need to change to make an other chart like this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script is looking for the id selector, in html the id is unique

so add a new div with antoher id and at the end of your script do

```
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
var chartOther = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material_other'));

chart.draw(data, options);
chartOther.draw(data, options );
```

if you want to use a classname you could draw the same charts for all elements with class some like this:

```
var charts = document.getElementsByClassName("yourclass");
for (var i = 0; i < charts; i++) {
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(charts[i]);
    chart.draw(data, options);

};
```

Comment: Thanks for all!!! But when I do that, the second chart is smaller than the first one, did you know anything about this?

Comment: you can add width and height properties to the options

Comment: John Smith , Yes but it doesnt change the dimension :( . its a bug or something?

Comment: no this is not a bug, is has sth. to do with your markup, checkout https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery